# Is there a way to recover removed git commits when local repository is not available?

Tags: git, github, commit, git-reset

I directly committed some changes to my GitHub repo remotely (inside the GitHub website). I then cloned this repo and did `git reset --hard HEAD~3` and `git push -f` to go back to previous commits and after doing this I removed the cloned (local) repository. It basically removed the first 3rd commits from my GitHub repository commit history. Now I am trying to recover the lost commits but I do not know if this is possible when the local repository is deleted?

Comment: GitHub still have the commits, but you'll need to have the hash IDs (at least the hash ID of the last of them). Do you have those?

Comment: I think I have the hash ID for one of them but I am not sure is it the last one or not.

Comment: OK, well, run `git fetch origin <hash-id>:refs/heads/recover` to create a new branch named `recover` in your local repository, pointing to the recovered commit(s). Then run `git log --decorate --oneline --graph recover` to view the commit(s). Note that this requires the full hash ID.

Comment: If you can find or recover the commit hash (maybe from GitHub UI?) it might be possible with the way that torek described.